# JSON-Taglib library not working w/ SDK 1.6?

Tags: json, maven-2, taglib, java-6, java-5

I'm currently working on a project that uses the json-taglib-0.4.1.jar library to do some json communication between front and back end.

That library use to work fine until we migrated to Java 1.6 recently, we were compiling against 1.5 before that.

On top of not working anymore, I read it's not available in public repositories, which means we cannot let the dependency being managed by Maven2, which would be ideal.

I really have 2 questions, has anyone been successful using that library in a Java 1.6 project? 
Does anyone know of a good replacement library that's actually available through Maven repositories? That'd actually be my favorite solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your other questions, but you can get json-taglib 0.4.1 from [mvnsearch.org's repository](http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/json-taglib/json-taglib/0.4.1/).

The repository URL is http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2 and the credentials are

```
<groupId>json-taglib</groupId>
<artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
<version>0.4.1</version>
```

Comment: Thank you Rich for the Maven Repository reference. Reading your post one more time made me wonder if the problem was just that the library hadn't been mavenised in the version of our project using JDK 1.6. I'll give that a shot Monday morning. Thanks again.